# How the make command invokes other subshells for recipe execution

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

For every recipe in target, make invokes a different subshell for recipe execution . 
So , I tried this command `strace make all 2>&1 | grep fork`, 
but did not get any matches for the `fork` system call. Where I am wrong ?

Comment: I wanted to know the number of fork calls executed by make while reading makefile

Comment: Was the target up to date by chance?  Remove the target and run to see if that works.  Your redirect `2>&1` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see calls to `fork` because the actual system call is `clone`.  You'll see this if you inspect the output of `strace`.  I like to save the strace output in a file and look at it afterwards:

```
strace -o trace make all
```

If I have a `Makefile` that looks like this:

```
three: one two
    cat one two > three

one:
    date > one

two:
    date > two
```

Then after running the `strace` command above, I have:

```
$ grep clone trace
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f6a3570ce50) = 29836
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f6a3570ce50) = 29838
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f6a3570ce50) = 29840
```

From the `fork` man page:

```
   C library/kernel differences
       Since version 2.3.3, rather than invoking the kernel's fork() system
       call, the glibc fork() wrapper that is provided as part of the NPTL
       threading implementation invokes clone(2) with flags that provide the
       same effect as the traditional system call.  (A call to fork() is
       equivalent to a call to clone(2) specifying flags as just SIGCHLD.)
       The glibc wrapper invokes any fork handlers that have been
       established using pthread_atfork(3).
```

Comment: Good answer! I never knew that `fork()` calls `clone()` under the hood. About saving the strace output in a file, I'm used to pipe into vim like this: `strace -e trace=process make test |& vi -`. That should even give you colors (depending on your vim settings of course)